# Power BI showing Totals in visualization matrix (table) only for one column?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

**Power BI** show Totals for two columns in visualization matrix (**bold** font data columns)
Switching off Totals just eliminate all totals columns, but I need Totals for one column that calculates total sums ("`Сумма в тенге`" column). No need in Totals for "`Страна`" column

[image]
[image]

---

**Data structure**: First column is company info. Then goes paired columns in each category. For example **Healing abutments** have two columns: `Sum` and `Country`. Then Implants have two columns also `Sum` and `Country`.
[image]

---

But overall Totals (bold font columns) that calculated automatically by the matrix show Totals for two of these columns. How to show totals only for one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to hide an individual Values field Total column.

The quickest solution is switch off `Text wrap` and `Auto-size width` under the `Column headers` property, then resize the column to be as thin as possible.

The other option would be to have only one Measure in the Values well of the matrix, then to have a new Table/column for the `Сумма в тенге` and `Страна` as two rows. Then you'd add that as a second level in the Columns well of the matrix. Then you would create a new Measure along the lines of:

```
Matrix value = 
  SWITCH(
    SELECTEDVALUE(Cat[Cat]),
    "Страна", [Страна]
    [Сумма в тенге]
  )
```